# Free Regex tool that can generate Java code?

Tags: java, regex, regexbuddy

While there are free alternatives to Regex Buddy when it comes to testing regular expressions, are there any alternatives regarding Java code generation?

Thanks for any hint :-)

Comment: If online tool is acceptable, I like this one: http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html

Comment: @azendh: That doesn't seem to do what the OP describes.

Comment: @azendh: like ruakh said: no code generation ):

Answer (score 0):

you can user notepad++ Regex helper plugin. It's really good and you can test your regex right away.

Comment: thanks, but according to the features on http://sourceforge.net/projects/nppregexhelper/ this tool does not generate any code.